# How to fix sqlite3 error using rails and ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

worked properly) here it is:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby ":

In Gemfile:

```
ruby  (~> 2.6.1.0) x64-mingw32

sass-rails (~> 5.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
  sass (~> 3.1) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
    sass-listen (~> 4.0.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 0.9.10, which depends on
        ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 1.9.18, which depends on
          ruby  (< 2.5) x64-mingw32

Could not find gem 'ruby  (< 2.5)', which is required by gem 'sqlite3', in any 
of the relevant sources: the local ruby installation
```

Comment: This Gemfile seems incorrect. What does it look like? If you need to require a particular version of Ruby, it's `ruby '<2.5'` not `gem 'ruby', '<2.5'`.

Comment: Try running ‘bundle update’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by adding

```
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
```